# Unable to assess SharePoint site from local client machine

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, port

SharePoint 2010 is hosted in Windows Server 2008 R2 in ISS 7.

There is two Port.

Port 1: http://ABCServer:5000/ - it is **accessible** from client machine. (**Running with Windows authentication**)

Port 2: http://ABCServer:6000/ - it is **not accessible** from client machine. (**Running with Farm authentication**)

I am getting Error **"This webpage is not available"**

How I can fix it?

Comment: Using non standard ports opens a load of firewall issues. Why not use 80 or if you must 8080?  Aside from that why are you hosting the same site on two different ports? Are you using port mapping and if so why?

Comment: 80 and 8080 also already exist. 2010 also exist for Central Admin. 5000 and 6000 new port for two different site running one(5000) with Win Auth and another one(6000) with Farm Auth.

Comment: 5000 port site is working fine and accessible form LAN, but 6000 not accessible

Comment: Is the website and application pool of the port :6000 site still running in IIS?

Comment: ya its running. Note: 6000 accessible with in server.